# Handle Akka actor bounded mailbox MessageQueueAppendFailedException

Tags: scala, akka, fault-tolerance

To avoid OOM, I'm bounding the mailbox size of some of my Akka 1.1.3 actors with a shared custom dispatcher. For example:

```
object Static {
    val dispatcher = Dispatchers.newExecutorBasedEventDrivenWorkStealingDispatcher(
        "customDispatcher",
        1000,
        BoundedMailbox(capacity = 10)
    )
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
    self.dispatcher = Static.dispatcher
    ...
}
```

I'd like to react to the mailbox overflowing so I can message the upstream producers to pause (side note: it sadly looks like `actor.stop()`, wait, and `actor.start()` will throw an `ActorStartException`). Some data loss is acceptable between the queue filling up and the queue draining a bit.

Akka's chapter on [Dispatchers](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/dispatchers.html#per-instance-based-configuration) says

> When trying to send a message to the Actor it will throw a
>   MessageQueueAppendFailedException(“BlockingMessageTransferQueue
>   transfer timed out”) if the message cannot be added to the mailbox
>   within the time specified by the pushTimeout.

Where can I catch this exception?

The documentation makes it sound like I need to wrap every `myActor ! message` in a try/catch. Is that right? I'd really like to centralize its handling. Can my `Supervisor` perhaps intercept it and run my handler?

Comment: What is the purpose of inspecting it?

Comment: Not sure if this would apply to your specific case, but if you're running into situations where you risk overflowing mailboxes, you may want to consider a "pull" design where your consumer actors ask for work from a producer rather than the producer spamming your consumers.

Comment: @Viktor it's to take upstream action, specifically to pause the consumers (I'll add this to the question). Dan is right, and I will definitely consider the pull model. However I'd like to do this right now with little rearchitecting, and data loss is acceptable.

Comment: And sorry, "inspect" maybe was a confusing word. All I need to know is that I've caught the `MessageQueueAppendFailedException` vs. some other exception.

Comment: I'd definitely switch to a pull-model in that case.

Comment: So it sounds like `MessageQueueAppendFailedException` can't be caught? @Viktor how do you feel about updating the docs then? Before posting here on SO I spent days figuring out where to catch it. Also, any resources on what the pull model looks like? Do consumer actors know they're falling behind by inspecting their own mailbox?

Comment: I'm not sure what lead you to believe that you can't catch that exception, but what would you do in that case?

Comment: I was lead to believe that by there being no answer to this SO question yet ;). If I could catch it, I would message the upstream producer to stop producing work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cc.spray.json._ since it is built on top of akka or twitter's finagle.